# python skype groupchat GET response error

Tags: python, chat, skype

I'm getting error in trying to communicate in a group chat via skype.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python38-32\ga.py", line 12, in 
>       skc.recent()
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\skpy\chat.py", line 452, in recent
>       info = self.skype.conn("GET", "{0}/threads/{1}".format(self.skype.conn.msgsHost, json.get("id")),
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\skpy\conn.py", line 219, in **call**
>       raise SkypeApiException("{0} response from {1} {2}".format(resp.status_code, method, url), resp)
>   skpy.core.SkypeApiException: ('404 response from GET https://azwus1-client-s.gateway.messenger.live.com/v1/threads/19:*********************', )
>   [Finished in 7.483s]

I'm just trying to test to send a simple chat to a groupchat but I'm not sure what is causing this error.
currently using this code

ch = sk.chats["19:***********************@thread.skype"]  *//due to privacy issue, i cant display the id*

ch.sendMsg("testing")

whereas if I use the code this way for creating a new conversation,

ch = sk.contacts["live@123"].chat

ch.sendMsg("testing")

it will work.

Can someone enlighten me what is the issue with it? really appreciate a lot.

Comment: Skype would produce this error in case your newly created user has not accepted an invitation to any channels/conversations. I hope this can help.